# Installing node-sass stuck on install.js

Tags: windows, npm, node-sass

Whenever I try to install node-sass via npm, this is what happens:

```
> node-sass@3.8.0 install C:\temp1\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

It gets stuck on the install.js line on a Windows 7 Machine. Any ideas?

Comment: I have recently observed this installation taking many minutes to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my case, wait a long time, you will see a warn 
`Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.8.0/win32-x64-46_binding.node":`

it mean your network are terrible or some gateway refused your access to github, like my country's GFW

so you can use a VPN to solve it

or go to this link and download this file`https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.8.0/win32-x64-46_binding.node`

then put it in your path like `D:\xxx\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-46\binding.node`

then in this pwd `\node_modules\node-sass\scripts>` and run `node ./install.js`

the download file maybe different for your different environment

just see the warning

but I fixed it in this way.

Best Wishes.